# To display only the active status for one specific id and for same id all status should be disabled

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle9i

I want to display person list who are Active for only one application starting 'a' and all other application should be 'DISABLED'.
Person id is in one table and  application details will be in another table.

Have to select the Person id who is satisfies the following condition. I have attached the model result in which I have joined the three table . I need to select user as below(Highlighted),

[image]

person_id is a primary key.

The query used as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM  (select   p.person_id from ur_username u join  ur_username_person up on u.username_id=up.username_id 
join ur_person p on up.person_id=p.person_id 
WHERE ( U.USERNAME  LIKE 'A-%' OR U.USERNAME  LIKE 'a-%')
AND u.status='ACTIVE' AND U.ROLE_ID =123 ) E
WHERE p.person_id IN ( select   p.person_id from ur_username u join  ur_username_person up on u.username_id=up.username_id 
join ur_person p on up.person_id=p.person_id 
WHERE ( U.USERNAME  NOT LIKE 'A-%' OR U.USERNAME NOT LIKE 'a-%')
AND u.status='DISABLED' AND U.ROLE_ID =123 )
```

I am getting the person who is active in any other application also.

In that above table i want the username a-pri (starts with a-) also with status 'ACTIVE' all the other status for application id 123 is disabled . no other username is active for that 123 id.

Comment: Are you using MS SQL Server or Oracle? Don't tag products not involved.

Answer (score 0):

We can try aggregating on the `Application_id` and then checking two things.  First, we can check that a username `a-pri` who is active appears once, and only once.  Second, we can assert that only one record appears as active.  These two conditions would seem to meet your requirements.

```
SELECT
    Application_id
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY
    Application_id
HAVING
    SUM(CASE WHEN username='a-pri' AND status='ACTIVE' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 1 AND
    SUM(CASE WHEN status = 'ACTIVE' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 1;
```

Follow the link below which uses a larger sample data set to cover more edge cases.

### Demo

Answer (score 0):

Probably I do not correctly understand your request, but here is my code:

```
Select username from your_rable where status = 'ACTIVE';
```

If this is not what you intend to receive, please provide more dataset, maybe for more Application_id and also the needed result.